# Presenting two modal viewcontrollers in a row causes the second one to not appear

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

The problem is as follows: in my applicationDidEnterBackground I modally present a viewcontroller, say viewcontroller A. So every time the app is launched A is onscreen. Now if during the execution of the app some other viewcontroller, say viewcontroller B, is presented modally and the app is sent to the background, and then you relaunch the app, A is not visible. And that is the problem.

I tried all kinds of different things, including presenting A and B from different viewcontrollers, presenting A from B if B is onscreen, presenting A after a delay, subclassing B and making it present A when the app becomes active... Nothing seems to work. I'm completely lost and I'm wondering if that is a bug. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to present those modal view controllers?

Comment: not much code to show really, just presenting viewcontrollers modally. each of them works perfectly when the other one is not present and they don't share anything to make them conflict with each other

Comment: I also had similar issue some times back. Actually what happens if you try to present two modalViewControllers at the same time is, the first modalViewController will alone be presented. The second one will not get presented. (i.e.)`Only one modalViewController can be presented at a time.`

Comment: Well, I've got a file hider app that presents a password screen every time it is launched. So if a UIImagePickerController of a MPMoviePlayerViewController is presented then there's absolutely no way to put those behind the screen when the app resumes?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rework your app so that you are not presenting 2 modal views. You can't have 2 modals presented so you need to take your pick.

Usually you can animate the transition effect of a view controller to mimic what you were using the presentModal for.

Comment: You actually can present two modal view controllers when the app is running normally. The problem is, you can't present a modal view  controller when entering background or foreground if there's another view controller already presented. I had to rework the app so it dismisses a modal view controller on entering background. Seems like there's no other way

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MDFPResenter class I wrote. You use it to present instead of the UIViewController methods. It calls the UIViewController methods, but it ensures the calls are queued up properly so your app does not crash.

https://github.com/mpdifran/MDFPresenter